# std::function has performances issues, how to avoid it?

Tags: c++, performance, machine-learning, statistics, c++17

I have classes which allow to **compound covariance functions** (also called Kernels see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228552/covariance-functions-or-kernels-what-exactly-are-they) and then compute the covariance given the new kernel for example :

```
auto C = GaussianKernel(50,60) + GaussianKernel(100,200);
auto result = C.covarianceFunction(30.0,40.0);
```

But The problem is that I call a `std::function` when I want to compute the covariance, **Is there a simple way to avoid it ?**
Note that I want to compute a big covariance matrix (approximately 50K*50K)  which means that performances matters.

**Here is the code**

```
class Kernel {
public: 
    /*
    Covariance function : return the covariance between two R.V. for the entire kernel's domain definition. 
    */
    virtual double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    )const = 0 ;
    ~Kernel() = default;
};

class FooKernel : public Kernel {
public:
    FooKernel(std::function<double(double, double)> fun) : fun_(fun) {}
    double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    ) const {
        return fun_(X, Y);
    }
    template<class T>
    auto operator+(const T b) const {
        return FooKernel([b, this](double X, double Y) -> double {
            return this->covarianceFunction(X, Y) + b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
        });
    }
    FooKernel operator=(const FooKernel other) const {
        return other;
    }
private:
    std::function<double(double, double)> fun_;
};

class GaussianKernel : public Kernel {
public:
    GaussianKernel(double sigma, double scale) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(scale) {}
    GaussianKernel(double sigma) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(1) {}
    /*
    A well known covariance function that enforces smooth deformations
    Ref : Shape modeling using Gaussian process Morphable Models, Luethi et al.
    */
    double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    ) const 
    {
        //use diagonal matrix
    doulbe result;
    result = m_scale  *  exp(-std::norm(X - Y) / (m_sigma*m_sigma));
    return result;      
    }
    template<class T>
    auto operator+(const T b) const {
        return FooKernel([b, this](double X, double Y) -> double {
            auto debugBval = b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
            auto debugAval = this->covarianceFunction(X, Y);
            auto test = debugBval + debugAval;
            return test;
        });
    }
private:
    double m_sigma;
    double m_scale;
};
```

Comment: What is the problem with using `std::function` ?

Comment: Should your destructor be virtual?

Comment: @Clonk It has severe performance issues, and I am using this function to compute a covariance matrix of size 50k*50k

Comment: So you don't have a `std::function` problem. You have a performance problem. Have you profiled your code ? Are you sure the use of `std::function` is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: @Clonk That's actually not unlikely to be the issue. Calls through `std::function` are extremely expensive due to type erasure. OP, the usual way around that is to write it in terms of templates somehow.

Comment: You can avoid this with expression templates. But those are not for the feint-of-heart...

Comment: @Baum mit Augen `std::function` is far from free in term of performance, but i'm just trying to be thorough. I've seen many times people jumping to conclusion regarding performance problem.

Comment: @Clonk Sure, that's sound advice in general. I was not trying to dispute that.

Comment: Good old C-style: Why not just store a pointer to an external function, if you are able to keep in on scope?

Comment: @Florent Jousse Do you need to change the function on the fly ? If not, you could use a templated derived class and specialize your  templated class with different function

Comment: @Clonk I don't need to change the function on the fly, but It's easy to use and intuitive with +overloading, isn't it ? (and can be extended easily to operator*, operator() etc)

Comment: Are there other functions you are interested in outside of covariance, or is covariance the only one?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Actually I'm interested only about covariance.

Comment: does anybody have any number about the run-time cost of std::function? The boost documentation https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/function/misc.html#id1285061 says Invocation efficiency
With a properly inlining compiler, an invocation of a function object requires one call through a function pointer. If the call is to a free function pointer, an additional call must be made to that function pointer (unless the compiler has very powerful interprocedural analysis).

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi I have read that you will be getting a 20 +- 10 nanosecond (i.e. clock cycle) overhead. The problem is often not even so much the call overhead but also the lack of inlining.

Comment: Please edit your post to make clear you have a performance problem and to include all the other information you've provided in comments.  Don't ask your readers to wade through the comments to discover your actual problem.

Comment: @MaxLanghof thanks

Comment: Also see [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). It provides compile time polymorphism and will allow you to flatten out the objects to avoid some overhead. The cost is a little more [coding] complexity and [mildly] interface programming. CRTP is an acquired taste...

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use clang/libc++ or gcc/libstdc++? The first one tends to optimize std::function better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

by templating FooKernel you can avoid the need for std::function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <functional>


class Kernel {
public: 
    /*
    Covariance function : return the covariance between two R.V. for the entire kernel's domain definition. 
    */
    virtual double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    )const = 0 ;
    ~Kernel() = default;
};


template <typename Func>
class FooKernel : public Kernel {
public:

    FooKernel(Func&& fun) : fun_(std::forward<Func>(fun)) {}
    double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    ) const {
        return fun_(X, Y);
    }
    template<class T>
    auto operator+(const T b) const {
        return make_foo_kernel([b, this](double X, double Y) -> double {
            return this->covarianceFunction(X, Y) + b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
        });
    }
    FooKernel operator=(const FooKernel other) const {
        return other;
    }
private:
   Func fun_;
};

template <typename Func>
auto make_foo_kernel(Func&& fun)
{
    return FooKernel<Func>(std::forward<Func>(fun));
}


class GaussianKernel : public Kernel {
public:
    GaussianKernel(double sigma, double scale) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(scale) {}
    GaussianKernel(double sigma) : m_sigma(sigma), m_scale(1) {}
    /*
    A well known covariance function that enforces smooth deformations
    Ref : Shape modeling using Gaussian process Morphable Models, Luethi et al.
    */
    double covarianceFunction(
        double   X,
        double   Y
    ) const 
    {
        //use diagonal matrix
    double result;
    result = m_scale  *  exp(-std::norm(X - Y) / (m_sigma*m_sigma));
    return result;      
    }
    template<class T>
    auto operator+(const T b) const {
        return make_foo_kernel([b, this](double X, double Y) -> double {
            auto debugBval = b.covarianceFunction(X, Y);
            auto debugAval = this->covarianceFunction(X, Y);
            auto test = debugBval + debugAval;
            return test;
        });
    }
private:
    double m_sigma;
    double m_scale;
};

int main()
{
    auto C = GaussianKernel(50,60) + GaussianKernel(100,200);
    auto result = C.covarianceFunction(30.0,40.0);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/2aRGJ1)

Comment: You need to actually use `make_foo_kernel` in the `operator+`. Then you can also chain them properly.

Comment: There are also several flaws in OP's code (taking by const value, an `operator=` that doesn't assign and just returns the rhs, to name a few). I don't know the policy on whether we should correct those, but I thought they were worth mentioning.

Comment: If the classes or at least the `covarianceFunction`s were final, a reasonably new gcc would dare to completely devirtualize the calls, rather than just doing speculative devirtualization. Also while the lambdas capture the right hand operand by value, `*this` is captured by reference, so the left operand of + must outlive the result to avoid UB.

Answer (score 1):

With this design, the only improvement over using `std::function` is to template-parameterize your classes, which can create other undesired problems.

```
template<class Fun>
class FooKernel : public Kernel {
public:
    FooKernel(Fun&& fun) : fun_(std::forward<Fun>(fun)) {}
...
private:
    Fun fun_;
};
```

If you don't want to template your class and If you need your classes to own a stateful function object, pretty much `std::function` is the only way to go.

However, if you don't need ownership or the the function or the function object is stateless (e.g. a free function) and you state that in your question I can give you an alternative option.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you liked the clarity of `std::function` you could try this non-owning function reference class:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename TSignature> class function_ref;

template<typename TRet, typename ...TParams>
class function_ref<TRet(TParams...)> final
{
    using refptr_t = void*;
    using callback_t = TRet (*)(refptr_t, TParams&&...);

    callback_t m_callback = nullptr;
    refptr_t m_callable = nullptr;

public:
    constexpr function_ref() noexcept = default;
    constexpr function_ref(const function_ref&) noexcept = default;
    constexpr function_ref& operator=(const function_ref&) noexcept = default;
    constexpr function_ref(function_ref&&) noexcept = default;
    constexpr function_ref& operator=(function_ref&&) noexcept = default;
    ~function_ref() noexcept = default;

    template <
        typename T,
        typename = typename std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_invocable_r_v<TRet, T(TParams...), TParams...> &&
            !std::is_convertible_v<std::decay_t<T>, function_ref>
        >
    >
    constexpr function_ref(T &&_callable) noexcept :
        m_callback(
            [](refptr_t callable, TParams&& ...params)
            {return (*reinterpret_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>*>(callable))(std::forward<TParams>(params)...);}
            ),
        m_callable(reinterpret_cast<refptr_t>(std::addressof(_callable))) 
    {}

    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(TParams&& ...params) noexcept 
    {
        return m_callback(m_callable, std::forward<TParams>(params)...);
    }

    constexpr operator bool() noexcept { return m_callback; }
};
```

This doesn't have the overhead of `std::function` as it doesn't need to own the callable, and with my tests it is usually completely inlined with `-O3` optimisations. This is my modified implementation of the class discussed by Vittorio Romeo in this [talk](https://youtu.be/6EQRoqELeWc). You still need to watch the lifetimes of the functions you pass to the constructor, however it is perfect to take function parameters.

Example usage:

```
void func(int x)
{
    std::cout<<x<< " I'm a free func!\n";
}

class Obj 
{
    public: 
    void member(int x) { std::cout<<x<< " I'm a member func!\n";}
};

int main()
{
    // Define the signature
    using func_ref_t = function_ref<void(int)>;

    // Can be used with stateful lambdas
    int bar = 1;
    auto lambda = [&bar](int x){std::cout<<x<< " I'm a lambda!\n"; ++bar;};

    // Copy and move
    func_ref_t lref(lambda);
    auto cpy = lref;
    auto mv = std::move(lref);
    cpy(1);
    mv(2);

    // See the modified var from the lambda
    std::cout<<bar<<'\n';

    // Use with free functions
    auto fref = func_ref_t{func};
    fref(4);

    // We can wrap member functions with stateful lamdas
    Obj obj;
    auto mem = [&obj](int x) { obj.member(x); };

    auto mref = func_ref_t{mem};
    mref(5);

}
```